# No "1" or infinite values and I still get: initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite

Tags: r, distribution, beta

I am trying to find parameters of Beta distribution.

My numeric vector's range (`myVector`) is from 1 to 1.4.

Writing

```
fitdistr(myVector, "beta", start=list(shape1=1/2, shape2=1/2))
```

it always returns

> Error in stats::optim(x = c(1.11751038937534, 1.18870025337922, 1.02241252436603,  : initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite

So I created `myVector_2` without any values equal to 1, but

```
fitdistr(myVector_2, "beta", start=list(shape1=1/2, shape2=1/2))
```

still returns

> Error in stats::optim(x = c(1.15007774000921, 1.01353198754175, 1.00201948705843,  : initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite

So, I tried to check if the values are finite, but

```
is.finite(myVector_2)
```

returns all `TRUE`.

This is the beginning of ordered `myVector_2`:

```
[1] 1.010020 1.010051 1.010068 1.010070 1.010073 1.010076 1.010082 1.010115
[9] 1.010125 1.010168 1.010201 1.010204 1.010228 1.010236 1.010244 1.010267
[17] 1.010268 1.010296 1.010297 1.010307 1.010335 1.010343 1.010353 1.010356
[25] 1.010357 1.010402 1.010403 ...
```

I've searched for hours, but none of the proposed solutions seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The beta distribution has range (0,1), so your data have to fall within this range.  If you know the range is 1 to 1.4 (with no values on the boundaries), you can easily scale your data to get them into (0,1).

Generate data:

```
set.seed(101)
rng <- c(1,1.4)
x1 <- rbeta(100,shape1=1/2,shape2=1/2)
x2 <- (x1*diff(rng)) + rng[1]
range(x2)
## [1] 1.000112 1.399849
```

Now scale the data back to (0,1):

```
x3 <- (x2-rng[1])/diff(rng)
range(x3)
## [1] 0.0002793899 0.9996217487
```

Now fit:

```
MASS::fitdistr(x3,"beta",start=list(shape1=1,shape2=1))
```

Works fine, albeit with warnings.

If your data are in the range [1,1.4] (i.e. including the ends) then something like `eps <- .0001; x3 <- (x2-rng[1]+eps)/(diff(rng)+2*eps)` should work to get it within (0,1).